# sympy not returning solution using solve

Tags: python, sympy

I'm attempting to calculate Lagrange multiplier using a question from this youtube video: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=B0yzLgJ6wn8, however using sympy.solve does not return solutions

I've coded this in python

```
import sympy as sp

x, y = sp.var('x y')

# constraint
g1 = 2 * x + y - 100
# function
f = 2 * x + 2 * x * y + y

# lambda
g1L = sp.Symbol('g1L')

fin_eqs = []
for i in [x, y]:
    fin_eqs.append(
        sp.Eq(
            sp.simplify(f.diff(i)), 
            sp.simplify(
                g1.diff(i) * g1L
            )
        )
    )
fin_eqs.append(sp.Eq(sp.simplify(g1), 0))


for i in fin_eqs:
    print(i)
"""
prints
Eq(2*y + 2, 2*g1L)
Eq(2*x + 1, g1L)
Eq(2*x + y - 100, 0)
which I've confirmed is correct
"""


sp.solve(fin_eqs, x, y) # returns []
```

However, it does not work out that x = 25 and y = 50

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have three equations and asked to solve for two unknowns:

```
In [20]: x, y, g1L = symbols('x, y, g1L')

In [21]: fin_eqs = [Eq(2*y + 2, 2*g1L), Eq(2*x + 1, g1L), Eq(2*x + y - 100, 0)]

In [22]: for eq in fin_eqs: pprint(eq)
2⋅y + 2 = 2⋅g1L
2⋅x + 1 = g1L
2⋅x + y - 100 = 0

In [23]: solve(fin_eqs, [x, y]) # asking for x and y
Out[23]: []
```

Since you did not ask to solve for `g1L` it is a symbolic parameter rather than an unknown. For almost all possible values of the symbolic parameter there are no solutions for `x` and `y` e.g.:

- if `g1L = 0` then there are no solutions for `x` and `y`.
- if `g1L = 1` then there are no solutions
- if `g1L = 2` ...

More generally we can summarise the situation as:

- If `g1L != 51` then there are no solutions (empty set)
- If `g1L = 51` then there is one solution.

Considering possible values of the parameter `g1L` the generic case here is the first case `g1L != 51`. For *almost all* possible values of the parameter `g1L` there are no solutions for `x` and `y` in the overdetermined system of equations. That is why `solve` returns `[]`.

From `solve`'s perspective it would be very presumptuous to suppose that `g1L` might happen to take the value `51` just because that is the only value that would make the equations consistent. It might seem obvious to you that `g1L` is a free parameter that can take any value as needed in order to make the equations consistent but how is `solve` supposed to know that?

Suppose instead `g1L` was called `e` and was supposed to represent a fixed quantity like "the mass of an electron". Is `solve` allowed to freely choose the value of the mass of an electron? Should `solve` return solutions that are only valid if `e = 51` even though that is almost certainly not the mass of an electron?

If you want `g1L` to be chosen freely as needed to make the equations consistent then you need to include it among the unknowns:

```
In [25]: solve(fin_eqs, [x, y, g1L]) # asking for x and y and g1L
Out[25]: {g1L: 51, x: 25, y: 50}
```

Alternatively as noted in the other answer you could omit specifying the unknowns in which case `solve` considers all symbols to be unknowns:

```
In [26]: solve(fin_eqs)
Out[26]: {g1L: 51, x: 25, y: 50}
```

Note that allowing solve to choose the unknowns like this is not what is wanted in general if there are supposed to be symbolic parameters in the equations e.g.:

```
In [11]: a, b, c, x = symbols('a, b, c, x')

In [31]: eq = Eq(a*x**2 + b*x + c, 0)

In [32]: eq
Out[32]: 
   2              
a⋅x  + b⋅x + c = 0

In [33]: print(solve(eq))
[{a: (-b*x - c)/x**2}]
```

Is it obvious that `x` was supposed to be the unknown rather than `a`? How should `solve` know that?

## Explanation:

When you solve a system of equations you need to say which variables are the "unknowns" e.g. given `a*x**2 + b*x + c = 0` do you want to solve for `x` or `a` or something else?

If the equations have symbols that are not part of the unknowns then those are symbolic "parameters". If `x` is the only unknown in `a*x**2 + b*x + c = 0` then `a`, `b` and `c` are parameters and you are trying to solve a symbolically parametrised equation for `x`.

When solving a parametrised system of equations it is often the case that the existence of the solutions depends on the values of the parameters. For example if solving `a*x**2 + b*x + c = 0` for `x` then there are several cases:

- `a != 0`: there are one or two solutions for `x`.
- `a = 0` and `b != 0`: there is one solution for `x`.
- `a = 0` and `b = 0` and `c = 0`: any value of `x` is a solution (the set of solutions is infinite).
- `a = 0` and `b = 0` and `c != 0`: there are no solutions (the empty set).

For *almost all* possible values of the symbolic parameters `a`, `b` and `c` the first case applies so this is the "generic" case. Each other case has an equality condition like `a = 0` making it a "degenerate" case.

SymPy's `solve` function aims to find the generic case among possible values of the parameters which if solving `a*x**2 + b*x + c = 0` for `x` is:

```
In [13]: eq
Out[13]: 
   2              
a⋅x  + b⋅x + c = 0

In [14]: solve([eq], [x])
Out[14]: 
⎡⎛           _____________ ⎞  ⎛           _____________ ⎞⎤
⎢⎜          ╱           2  ⎟  ⎜          ╱           2  ⎟⎥
⎢⎜   b    ╲╱  -4⋅a⋅c + b   ⎟  ⎜   b    ╲╱  -4⋅a⋅c + b   ⎟⎥
⎢⎜- ─── - ────────────────,⎟, ⎜- ─── + ────────────────,⎟⎥
⎣⎝  2⋅a         2⋅a        ⎠  ⎝  2⋅a         2⋅a        ⎠⎦
```

These solutions for `x` are valid provided `a != 0` which is the generic case.

For this equation the generic case is that solutions *exist*. However for your system of equations treating `g1L` as a parameter the generic case is that solutions for `x` and `y` *do not exist*.

Answer (score 1):

For some reason, to get result you need to omit all the symbols you're solving on or pass all symbols.

`sp.solve(fin_eqs)` and `sp.solve(fin_eqs, x, y, g1L)` returns `{g1L: 51, x: 25, y: 50}`

`sp.solve(fin_eqs, x)` and `sp.solve(fin_eqs, x, y)` returns empty list.

Documentation is confusing, all I get that it tries different strategies depending on the number of symbols provided.

Comment: Thanks for your help, did you just trial and error this or is there a list somewhere that suggests possible fixes? Looking online, sympy does seem to be a bit weird sometimes

Comment: Yes, I did trial and error